# Migrating Tomcat from 8.0 to 8.5, Client Certificate authentication not working

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, networking, certificate

We are upgrading our Tomcat server from 8.0 to 8.5. Our sever should support https including mutual authentication, `certificateVerification`, using defaults of tomcat JSSE options.
currently it seems that mutual authentication is not working because the server cannot verify the 
client certificate.

The Connector configuration in tomcat goes as follows:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" >
         <SSLHostConfig truststoreFile="/opt/allot/conf/infra.truststore" truststoreType="JKS" truststorePassword="****"
                         certificateVerification="required" sslProtocol="TLS" protocols="TLSv1.2,+TLSv1.1,+TLSv1.0">
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/opt/allot/conf/infra.keystore"
                         certificateKeystoreType="JKS"
                         certificateKeystorePassword="****"
                         certificateKeyAlias="****" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

I used WireShark sniffer to and the output is:

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
260 5.228627    172.19.2.30 10.110.108.74   TCP 66  55710 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
261 5.230733    10.110.108.74   172.19.2.30 TCP 66  443 → 55710 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1387 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
262 5.230831    172.19.2.30 10.110.108.74   TCP 54  55710 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131584 Len=0
263 5.252688    172.19.2.30 10.110.108.74   TLSv1.2 238 Client Hello
264 5.254772    10.110.108.74   172.19.2.30 TCP 56  443 → 55710 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=185 Win=30336 Len=0
265 5.268445    10.110.108.74   172.19.2.30 TCP 1441    443 → 55710 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=185 Win=30336 Len=1387 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
266 5.268564    10.110.108.74   172.19.2.30 TLSv1.2 887 Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
267 5.268607    172.19.2.30 10.110.108.74   TCP 54  55710 → 443 [ACK] Seq=185 Ack=2221 Win=131584 Len=0
268 5.329682    172.19.2.30 10.110.108.74   TLSv1.2 136 Certificate, Client Key Exchange
269 5.333364    10.110.108.74   172.19.2.30 TLSv1.2 61  Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Bad Certificate)
270 5.333365    10.110.108.74   172.19.2.30 TCP 56  443 → 55710 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2228 Ack=267 Win=30336 Len=0
271 5.333456    172.19.2.30 10.110.108.74   TCP 54  55710 → 443 [ACK] Seq=267 Ack=2229 Win=131584 Len=0
273 5.365042    172.19.2.30 10.110.108.74   TLSv1.2 60  Change Cipher Spec
274 5.366449    10.110.108.74   172.19.2.30 TCP 56  443 → 55710 [RST] Seq=2229 Win=0 Len=0
```

This is my first experience with mutual authentication, I'd love to hear your advice and of course I'll share the solution as soon as I can.

**Edit**
I'm attaching my test client wrote in java, this piece of code working with tomcat 8.0.28 but not with Tomcat 8.5.50

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        disableSslVerification();
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path/to/trustStoreFile");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path/to/keyStoreFile");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "****");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "****");

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        URL url = new URL("https://10.110.108.74/webui");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String str = null;
        while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void disableSslVerification() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I manged to figure it out.
The problem were at our truststore file, the certificate was added with `PrivateKeyEntry` instead of `TrustedCeritciateEntry`.
Therefore the Tomcat server sent Certificate request without our internal CA.

Answering to persons which will counter that sometime.